# Where to find extended information about menuconfig kernel configuration options?

Tags: kernel, real-time

**Where to find extended information about `menuconfig` options?**

I am especially interested in those related with improving latency/jitter of a `RT_PREEMT` kernel (apart of the obvious `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL`).

### Some context

Trying to improve the Jitter of a `RT_PREEMPT` kernel, I need to understand deeply some of the configuration options of the kernel, those available with `menuconfig` command line.

After searching on Internet, I found only the one-line description already available in the `menuconfig` interface. But due to my "low" knowledge of the kernel, most of them stay obscure to me, or at least not fully clear.

The project consists of building a real time software on a small one-board computer, but after patching the kernel and building everything, I still get quite random jitter (speaking of up to 0.5ms under load, when I would need 0.050ms or less)

Related pages:

https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/preemptrt_setup

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menuconfig

Comment: The documentation, such as it is, is in a subdirectory of the kernel source.

Answer (score 0):

The following link was of help:

https://www.dotslashlinux.com/post/the-linux-kernel-configuration-guide-part-1-introduction/

Comment: the following link is dead, that's why the relevant content should be provided in an answer -1

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is copyrighted, but I let's you the opportunity to post your notes and get up-votes. 
In the while, I just updated the link so it works again (seem the author changed the title)